# Can you pass a class into a Rails datetime select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to format a Datetime select helper by passing in a class like so has not been working. I at first thought Bootstrap might be wrong, but after looking at the source, 'span2' is not there.

```
<%= f.datetime_select :arrival_nor_tendered, class: "span2" %>
```

This seems like the headslap way to do it but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :arrival_nor_tendered, {}, { class: "span2" } %>
```

The last parameter is `html_options` but it has a hash parameter before it and ruby may missinterpret the two.